# How Do i Make The Button Dispear When I go to next screen

Tags: p5.js

This is the code of the game I'm working on. I want to know how to make the button go away when I press it. I have already tried putting hide.button in a few places but don't know if they were the right spots. I'm just learning how to code. Please help me figure this out. I also tried looking it up but couldn't find the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Gji.png

Comment: Please post your code to show us what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/hide) from p5 itself that shows how to hide items, you can make the button a function by:

```
let button = createButton(**button settings**);
button.hide();
```

I see you tried to put `button.hide()` , but most likely did not make "button" a function, therefore p5 did not know what "button" was.

Hope that helped! Happy coding!

EDIT: Before you put

```
button.hide();
```

Try putting it in an if statement as below:

```
    let button = createButton(**button settings**);
if(button.mousePressed){
    button.hide();
}
```

Then put that in your sketches setup function